# Setting textboxes back to default styling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some jQuery that loops over form input elements and if it finds that they are empty, it sets their `border-color` to be red.  When the submit button is clicked, it checks the elements again, and if there are elements with data, then I'm attempting to set the textbox back to it's original style.

I have tried using `border-style: solid / none / initial` and `border-color: black` but the box either ends up looking very bold, or having no border at all.  Here is the code :

```
function validateForm() {
        isValid = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                isValid = false;
                alert('Please fill a value in for : ' + $(this).attr('name'));
            }
            else {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'black');
                $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
            }
        });

        if (isValid) {
            $('#contactForm').submit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really simple method if your using style sheets is to just do $(input).attr('style', '') this will clear all styles made on the input itself (basically resetting it back to what your style sheet has defined)

Comment: @Camway - post that as an answer.

Comment: @Taplar - post that as an answer.

Comment: As a side note, you should add a new variable, `var $this = $(this);`, in your `.each(` callback and change all your references to `$(this)` to use that variable. For example, after adding the variable you will change `$(this).val() ...` to `$this.val() ...`. We do this because the `$(...)` is actually a function call and can be thought of like a constructor, creating a new jQuery object each time. Rather than recreate `$(this)` each time, we store it in a variable, `$this`, for reuse. This can dramatically improve performance in some situations.

Comment: Look at @Taplar's solution, which uses `$this`. His is the cleanest and most efficient solution thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using style sheets, this should work for resetting the input:

```
$(input).attr('style', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a class could help, and also possibly reduce your logic:

```
function validateForm() {
    var formValid = true;

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() === "") {
            $this.addClass('errorClass');
            formValid = false;
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('errorClass');
        }
    });

    if (formValid) {
        $('#contactForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Missing required fields.  Please review and try again.');
    }
}
```

Where 'errorClass' is

```
errorClass { border-color: #F00; }
```

Comment: While somewhat more condensed, your solution actually runs slower than the original `.each(function() { ...if...else...` implementation. The original runs in `O(n)` time (as it loops through the collection once) while yours runs in `O(3n)` time (as it loops through the collection three times - once for each input. I will upvote once this is changed back.

Comment: Upvoting now, assuming that you will remove the other `.filter` call

Comment: You really feel a filter on a finite set is a big performance hit?

Comment: No, but it's more of a performance hit than the OP included, which makes it not the best solution. We should be clean when we can ;)

Comment: Also, awesome use of `$this` before I could finish writing my suggestion comment!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly set the border color using `$(this).css('border-color', 'red')`, create a class with a style of `border-color: red` and use `$(this).addClass(className)` and `$(this).removeClass(className)` to add and remove the styling.

```
function validateForm() {
    isValid = true;
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).addClass('redBorderClass');
            isValid = false;
            alert('Please fill a value in for : ' + $(this).attr('name'));
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('redBorderClass');
        }
    });

    if (isValid) {
        $('#contactForm').submit();
    }
}
```